# append arguments with matlab command

Tags: matlab

I have a function :

```
function  launchMe(values)

launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2)
end
```

I would like to create a function that can add to the basic launch other arguments

function myFunc(values,..)
end

and this function will call the launch with default args and if additiolas args=> it added them to the launch function

```
myFun(values) => launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2)
myFun(values,'toto') => launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2,'toto')
myFun(values,'arg3','tata') => launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2,'arg3','tata')
```

is there a specific matlab command to add args and values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be achieved using the [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) mechanism:

```
function myFunction(varargin)
    launch('arg1', 'value1', varargin{:})
end
```

Now you can do

```
myFunction('arg2', 'value2')
myFunction('arg2', 'value2', 'arg3', 'value3')
```

these calls are equivalent to

```
launch('arg1', 'value1', 'arg2', 'value2')
launch('arg1', 'value1', 'arg2', 'value2', 'arg3', 'value3')
```

If you also want to pipe through the output arguments of `launch` then things get slightly more complex:

```
function varargout = myFunction2(varargin)
    if nargout == 0
        launch('arg1', 'value1', varargin{:});
    else
        varargout = cell(1, nargout);
        [varargout{:}] = launch('arg1', 'value1', varargin{:})
    end
end
```

Now you can do (assuming that `launch` returns the correct number of arguments):

```
myFunction2('arg2', 'a')
result = myFunction2('arg2', 'b')
[result1, result2] = myFunction2('arg2', 'c')
```

Comment: what I'm looking for is : each time I call myFunc(argsn,valueN,..) it appends the basic launch by adding args and values

Comment: @lola: That's just what the first part of my answer does, if I understand you correctly. What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: yes, but for example the default call to launch is launch('arg','value'); so I would like to call it with default args or with also addistional args for example : if I call myFunction(default) it calls the default launch and if I call myFunction('arg2',val2) it calls launch('arg','value','arg2',val)

Comment: @lola: If you use my definition of `myFunction` then you can do `myFunction()` (which is equivalent to `launch('arg1', 'value1')`) and `myFunction('arg2', 'value2')` (which is equivalent to `launch('arg1', 'value1', 'arg2', 'value2')`).